# Select renderValue function not being called [ReactJS/Material-UI]

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I have a select function within a material-table ([a module which I installed](https://material-table.com/#/docs/get-started)). I am also using the Chips component from Material-UI. However, in this function I have tried troubleshooting why nothing appears when I select something and it seems that my renderValue function is not being called.

Here is the code:

```
function handleChange(event) {
    console.log("!")
    setRoleIds(event.target.value);
  }

  const renderChip = (value) => {
    console.log("?!??!?");
    console.log(value);
    return <Chip label={value} className={classes.chip} />;
  };

  const [cassowaries, setCassowaries] = React.useState({
    columns: [
      { title: "Cassowary Name", field: "name" },
      {
        title: "Cassowary Roles",
        field: "roles",
        render: (rowData) => {
          return (
            <li>
              {rowData.roles.map((role) => (
                <Chip label={role} className={classes.chip} />
              ))}
            </li>
          );
        },
        editComponent: (props) => (
          <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
            <InputLabel>Roles</InputLabel>
            <Select
              multiple
              value={roleIds}
              onChange={handleChange}
              input={<Input id="select-multiple-chip" />}
              renderValue={renderChip}
              // MenuProps={MenuProps}
            >
              {allRoleIds.map((id) => (
                <MenuItem key={id} value={id}>
                  {id}
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </Select>
          </FormControl>
        ),
      },
      { title: "Penguin", field: "penguin" },
    ],
    data: [{ name: "Mehmet", roles: roleIds, penguin: true }],
  });
```

Would someone be able to help or guide me please?

Comment: Please provide a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you have the following properties set:

```
<Select
native={false}
displayEmpty={true}
...
</Select>
```

You have to set `displayEmpty={true}` to make it to render if the value is empty and `native={false}` because `renderValue()` works only for non native selects according to the [docs](https://v4.mui.com/api/select/#props).